Albumentations intensity augmentations disrupt the image
I'm using a preprocessed, z-score normalized list as the source for my dataset.
Here's a collage of images augmented by Albumentations:
enter image description here
Here's my Compose:
augmentation = A.Compose([
    A.HorizontalFlip(),
    A.RandomBrightnessContrast(brightness_limit=(-0.0001, 0.0001), contrast_limit=(-0.01, 0.01)),
    A.CoarseDropout(8, 0.1, 0.1),
    A.Rotate(limit=15),
    A.Affine(shear=(-2, 2), scale=(0.95, 1.05)),
>! ToTensorV2()
])

On the 50% of the images that RandBrightnessContrast is applied even with very small parameters, the whole distribution of the image is squashed to [0, 1] (from ~-2,~2 as expected for z-score normalized images).
Any way around this?
Maybe I should perform z-score normalization after these, but my original intent was to separate all deterministic steps (resize, normalize etc.) from the augmentation steps for efficiency.

Albumentations indeed, treats images of the type float32 as having min value of 0 and max value of 1.
If your images are in [-2, 2] range, you may rescale your image to [0, 1] with:
def convert_to_01(image):
    return (image + 2) / 4    

and later rescale back with
def convert_from_01(image):
   return (image * 4) - 2

If possible, you may even convert images to [0, 255] uint8 type, as transforms in uint8 happen much faster.
P.S. Thank you for the question, I will make it clear in the documentation of Albumentations that float32 images are expected to be in [0, 1] range.
